# how to call a function in another controller in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to call a function in another controller. for example if user try to log in with incorrect parameter then the application will redirect to another controller and passing a variable (array).

```
class User extends Controller {

function User()
{
   parent::Controller();
}

function doLogin()
{
  $userData = $this->users->getAuthUserData($user,$password);
  if(empty($userData)){ 
   // this is where i need to call a function from another controller
  }else{
   echo 'logged in';
  }
}

}
```

is it possible passing a variable using redirect() function in url helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php    
$array = array('foo'=>'bar', 'baz'=>'fubar', 'bar' => 'fuzz');

    $json = json_encode($array);

    $encoded_json= urlencode($json);
    /* now pass this variable to your URL redirect)

    /* on your receiving page:*/
    $decoded_json= urldecode($encoded_json);

    /* convert JSON string to an array and output it */
    print_r(json_decode($decoded_json, true));
?>
```

this code:

takes an array, converts it to a JSON encoded string.

we then encode the `$json` string using `url_encode`. You can pass this via the url.

Decode this URL, then decode the JSON object as an associative array.

might be worth a try

Comment: Agreed: For an array JSON and urlencoding is definitely the best choice.

Comment: ok.. i will try it.. thanks.. is there any limit of lenght of http url?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use redirect('othercontroller/function/'.url_encode($data), 'location');

That should work.

edit: you could also put the code in a helper.

Comment: is it possible if $data is array?

Comment: `urlencode` (no underscore) expects a string, so no an array won't work. see my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function of one controller from another controller then you can use redirect Helper.

For example:

```
class Logout extends CI_Controller { 

     function index() {     
        session_destroy();
        redirect('index.php/home/', 'refresh');
     } 

}
```

it will call another contoller.